# Image precaching

Tags: css, image, onload

at the website I'm working on [euroworker.no](http://euroworker.no/), I have a ton of CSS rollovers, that only load when rolled over, is there a way to force load these onLoad so that they don't flash when rolled over the first time? It makes the site look broken. I could use a `<body onLoad...>` but am not sure how to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use [image sprites](http://alistapart.com/articles/sprites). In short, this means you put both states of an image (default and hover) in one image file. Upon hover, you then shift the `background-position` of the element in question.

Comment: Oh yes, I should do that, I have done this before, stupid me for forgetting it :P Thanks!